# Laravel routing using array with Auth:check() but failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and try to code my route like below

```
Route::get('quest', [
    'uses' => (Auth::check()) ? "RegisteredController@quest":"UnregisteredController@quest"
]
);
```

I want to differentiate the output for logged user but can't get it working. The route still goes to 'UnregisteredController' whether a user logged or not. But my other route like below is working.

```
Route::get('login', function() {
if (Auth::check())
    return Redirect::intended('home');
return view('login');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` bring for 5.1? Can you edit your question with that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**routes.php** is loaded during application bootstraping - before request processing starts and before Laravel loads user from the session. Therefore you'll always get false from **Auth::check()** if you call it when the file is loaded. That's why the first route definition doesn't work as you need it to.

In the second case, **Auth::check()** is called during request processing, so user has already been loaded and you get the results you want.

If you want to differentiate output depending on whether user is authenticated or not, you should do the check either in controller, and return different views, or in the view.

Comment: Oh. I changed the coding to check it in a controller. Thank you for the explanation.